# Redmine cannot start after installing by bitnami

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I've installed fresh Bitnami redmine 4.0.1-1 , using windows 10 ,but when I try to "go to application" it opens a Bitnami page and when I try to access redmine through it gives me:

> Not Found The requested URL /redmine/ was not found on this server.

While opening (manage servers) tab , i found that (thin_redmine and thin-redmine2) are stopped and not working

I've installed the Bitnami Support Tool and it gives me this code:

d84e3adc-0777-8b8e-1e74-460ad477e918

Comment: Is there something else already using ports on which Redmine/Thin should work?

Comment: Mysql database and Apache web server are running well

Comment: Then it means you can't run two instances on same machine, ports are already taken...  Stop that instance, then retry redmine...

Comment: but all these servers are mandatory to run redmine

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. We tested the solution and it works out-of-the-box when using a Windows machine. Could you please share the content of the log files inside the `installdir/apps\redmine\htdocs\log` directory?